# Entity Framework / Linq: Efficiently detect if all elements exist in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

**Addition after comment,** my question was not clear enough

Some software accessed a database and retrieved a collection of items. He selected a subset of them and called me to ask to process the collection.
Between the other software's access to the database and its call to me items  might be removed by others.

Other Process:

```
IEnumerable<MyType> itemsToProcess = FetchItemsToProcess();
Process(itemsToProcess);
```

My procedure:

```
void Process(IEnumerable<MyType> items)
{
   ...
}
```

The collection of `items` is fairly small, and normally all items are expected to be present in the database, with unchanged primary and foreign keys, However I can't be sure whether all items still exist.

**Continuing original question**

It is not a problem if during processing I detect that an item does not exist in the database anymore, it is only a waste of time. Therefore before processing I want to check if all items exist in the database.

I have checked that all items in my sequence have a non-zero ID. Now I need to check if all IDs are IDs of existing items in the database:

Not efficient solution: get the Ids of all existing items into local memory and use `Except`

```
IEnumerable<MyType> itemsToProcess = ...
IEnumerable<int> idsToProcess = itemsToProcess.Select(item => item.Id);
IEnumerable<int> existingIds = myDbContext.MyItems.Select(item => item.Id);

bool nonExistingItemsDetected = idsToProcess.Except(existingIds).Any();
```

The following method requires one DB accesses per item to check:

```
IEnumerable<MyType> itemsToProcess = ...
IEnumerable<int> idsToProcess = itemsToProcess.Select(item => item.Id);
bool nonExistingItemsDetected = idsToProcess
    .Where(idToProcess => !myDbContext.MyItems.Any(item => item.Id == idToProcess);
```

Because the sequence of items to process is fairly small I'd like to use the database to detect if any ID does not exist. I think I need to make an `IQueryable` with a  `Contains`

```
bool nonExistinItemsDetected = myDbContext.MyItems
  .Any( ?? )
```

What predicate can I use to detect if idsToProcess contains ids of items that do not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to process the items anyway, you'll need to get them from the database.  In which case, you might as well use something like the following to obtain the matching items:

```
var existingDbItems = dbContext.MyItems.Where(i => localIdCollection.Contains(i.Id));
```

Then you can simply check that the count of distinct id's matches the number of records returned before proceeding.

Ensure the collection of id's that you use `.Contains()` on is an in-memory collection (not a store expression) otherwise you may see an exception.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, you could change the query above to:

```
var existingDbItemsCount = dbContext.MyItems
     .Where(i => localIdCollection.Contains(i.Id)).Distinct().Count();
```

So that you're only obtaining the count, rather than all the records.

If the items are so volatile that you have to check they exist at this point, unless you're working within a transaction, there still may be problems by the time your code modifies the database.

Comment: The problem is, someone retrieved the items from the database, selected several from them and called my procedure to ask to process them. I don't need to access this table again, I have all information I need. For processing I need to access other tables using the information in my table. I'll update the question, to make this clear

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse I've edited edit my answer accordingly

Comment: The Count() did it: this way I don't have to retrieve anything from MyItems, only the number that match. All I have to do is check if the Count equals the number of items I have to process. By the way: my processing does not change the database, so transactions would not help, all I have to know is that it is worth doing the processing, instead of throwing the results away if at the end of the process if I detect the item is not used anymore